# In Node exec callback response not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, child-process

I have a route that handles a url post request inside I run an exec on a bash command. For some reason, the console.log works so I know the bash command ends and the callback is being entered. However the response will not let me send anything. If I move the response outside of the scope of the exec callback, then data will be sent and received by my client. Right now response doesn't send anything. I don't get an error either.

```
router.post('/someurl', function (req, res) {
    exec('some command', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if(error) {
        console.error('exec error: '+error);
        }
        console.log(stdout);
        res.send(stdout);
    });
 });
```

Comment: try `res.redirect(someURL)`

Comment: Try `res.send()`. You have `response.send()`.

Answer (score 0):

`response` is **undefined** and you are trying to call method on it, so use `res` since it appears in route handler as a parameter `function(req, res){...}`

```
res.send(stdout);
```

Comment: That was an error on my part. I didn't copy paste the code exactly from my text editor. The problem is a bit more deep than that.

Comment: @user8359904 you are using `exec` on air, it should be somehow related to child_process module

Comment: I declare exec in the top of my file.
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

Comment: did you try `res.redirect(someGetURL)` ?

Comment: What would res.redirect do? I thought it was only used to go to a different URL. How would I be able to get the stdout from the exec then?

Comment: if redirect works stdout should probably be stringified

Comment: I will delete the answer if didn't help?

Comment: I don't know how I would redirect the stdout. It didn't help me.